# Error code -36 - cp: Input/output error - mac

Tags: macos, external-disk

While I'm coping the file from the External hard drive to my MacBook Pro I'm getting Error code -36. Some recommended for dot_clean option, also I've tried and facing the same issue. Even I've tried to copy through the Terminal and also getting IO error. Desperately need to copy my stuff from my external drive.

Comment: What does "Some recommended for dot_clean option, also I've tried and facing the same issue." mean.  Also how is the external disk connected and how is it formatted. What is the exact output in the terminal

Comment: dot_clean option is to remove the .DS_Store hidden file from the folder.

WD My Book 2TB External Hard Drive Storage USB 3.0 with External Power Adapter.

The format type is FAT32.

Error msg in the system.log
Jun 20 06:55:27 Gowthamans-MacBook-Pro.local wirelessproxd[80]: Failed to start advertising (Unknown error.) for identityservicesd
Jun 20 06:55:27 Gowthamans-MacBook-Pro.local sharingd[278]: 06:55:27.354 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))

Comment: That comment should be an edit to the question and I still don't understand don_clean option - I can understand delete .DS_Store so I must assume that is different

Answer (score 2):

In a Terminal:

```
grep "I/O error" /var/log/system.log
```

This will output to the Terminal all lines in the system.log file that has `I/O error` in it. Output such as `kernel[0]: disk0s2: I/O errors` are indicative of a falling and or damaged HDD. Note `disk0s2` is an example and depending on which disk and partition has bad sectors the disk number and slice number will be different then the example. If you have output such as this and aren't backed up then do it before doing anything else!

Note; Depending on when the last time you had an error copying something it may not be in the current `system.log` file and you'll ether need to check the archived system logs or `grep` directly after the copy error.

If the copy is failing just on a particular file, you can attempt a recovery using `ddrescue` on the target file to try and copy it. `ddrescue` is a third-party utility that will need to be installed however `dd` is a part of OS X and it too can be used, although `ddrescue` offers more control and options then `dd` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Let me check on this and get back to you :)